# Excel Countif in a macro

Tags: excel

My countif function works fine in the excel sheet itself as shown below

`=COUNTIF(F111506:K111519,">0")`

I however do not get the same results when executing this in a macro. Stepping through the macro, I do the see the correct range highlighted.

```
nonZeroCount = Application.CountIf(Range(("F" & curRow + 5), ("K" & curRow + 18)).Select, ">0")
```

I always get a value of 0. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
nonZeroCount = Application.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shName").Range("F" & curRow + 5 & ":K" & curRow + 18), ">0")
```

where `shName` relevant sheet name.

Or another way:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shName")
    nonZeroCount = Application.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(curRow + 5, "F"), .Cells(curRow + 18, "K")), ">0")
End With
```

Comment: That didn't work either. Still get a value of 0. I do have other code that basically steps through each of the cells in the range and returns the correct values. I just wanted to have this since this would be shorter.

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the Evaluate command:

```
FormulaResultCount = Evaluate("CountA(C:C)")
```

Replace the stuff in quotes with your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get your desired result is

```
 nonZeroCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F" & curRow + 5, "K" & curRow + 18), ">0")
```